# Underscore how to filter the object keep 2 approach in condition?

Tags: underscore.js

I have 2 object arrays. I just want to filter the 2nd array using the first arrays values, the constrain is,

a) first array's part 'section' and '/' - values not allowed in second array.

how to loop through 2 of these arrays and filter the required object as an array. here is the my try:

```
var array1 = [
    {
        "part" : "section",
        "id"    : "3",
    },
    {
        "part" : "page",
        "id"    : "1"
    },
    {
        "part": "/",
        "id" : "4"
    },
    {
        "part": "/",
        "id" : "5"
    },
    {
        "part": "/",
        "id" : "6"
    }
];


var array2 = [
    {
        "name" : "dog",
        "value" : "3"
    },
    {
        "name" : "rabbit",
        "value": "1", //it is allowed, since it's not fall under 'section' or '/'
    },
    {
        "name" : "rose",
        "value": "4"
    },
    {
        "name" : "lilly",
        "value": "5"
    },
    {
        "name" : "egle",
        "value": "6"
    },
    {
        "name" : "horse",
        "value": "7"
    },
    {
        "name" : "cat",
        "value": "8"
    }
]

_.each(array1, function(item){
   var fitered =  _.filter(array2, function(fltItm){
       return fltItm.value !== item.part('page').id || fltItm.value !== item.value;
    })
})
```

But I am not getting the proper result. my result should be:

```
var array2 = [

    {
        "name" : "rabbit",
        "value": "1",
    },
    {
        "name" : "horse",
        "value": "7"
    },
    {
        "name" : "cat",
        "value": "8"
    }
]
```

How to achieve this? any one advice me the best way?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yxx2r/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `array1` by the `id` value and then filter, like this:

```
var map = {}, filtered;

_.each(array1, function (item) {
    map[item.id] = item.part;
})

filtered = _.filter(array2, function (item) {
    var part = map[item.value];

    return part !== '/' && part !== 'section';
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yJWvZ/1/